# How do I set up a local version of my https wordpress site for testing and development using MAMP

Tags: ssl, localhost

I have a production wordpress website that has a SSL Certificate and I have duplicated it onto my Mac and am trying to set up a testing environment but I can't view it in my browser.  I get the following Error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> localhost sent an invalid response.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I tried to set up a certificate using [this tutorial](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-mamp/) but when I got up to the section

> To add the rootCA.pem file, click on the plus sign near the bottom-left corner of ‘Keychain Access’. Add the rootCA.pem file and you will see it listed with a red cross, notifying you the certificate is not trusted.

My computer would throw this error

> Error: -25294 when trying ot add rootCA.pem file to certificates

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I would also be happy to hear any simple solutions to Local hosts and SSL.

Thank you.

Comment: While server setup is on topic here, this case sounds quite specific and you might get better answers from developers/support of the web server stack you are using.